# Bootstrap does not perfectly center the content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this simple code:

```
      <div class="container branduri justify-content-center">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
 <div class="col-xl-4">
  <h1><strong>+100</strong></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xl-4">
  <h1><strong>+100</strong></h1>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xl-4">
   <h1><strong>+100</strong></h1>
 </div>
```

The issue is that on my website, as you can see in attached photo, the columns it is not centered perfectly. Why?
[image: SS]
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will be useful a fiddle example to help you

Answer (score 2):

Add bootstrap class **text-center** on your row div

```
class="row justify-content-center text-center"
```

Comment: Just to elaborate so OP knows why this fixes the issue; the columns inside the row ARE centered (in reality they don't event have to use `justify-content-center` because they are using all the available space in the row since each column spans 4 spaces.) But the problem is the **content** inside of the columns is not centered, which is solved by using `text-center`.

Comment: @IvanS95 Exactly!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to center the text within each column by adding this property to the row `text-align:center;` or adding the Bootstrap class `text-center` as follows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container branduri justify-content-center">
     <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
               <h1><strong>+100</strong></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
               <h1><strong>+100</strong></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
               <h1><strong>+100</strong></h1>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of style="text-align:center;" he can use boostrap class text-center